# Applying $exists to MongoDB aggregation

Tags: mongodb

I have two mongo collections structured like so:

**customers**

```
{
   _id: ObjectId,
   name: String,
   companyId: ObjectId
}
```

**companies**

```
{
   _id: ObjectId,
   name: String,
   rights: [
     add: boolean,
     edit: boolean,
     shop: boolean
   ]
}
```

So each **customer** has a **companyId** that lets us look up the **companies.rights** available. I need to get a list of which companies have customers but don't have the **shop** property at all.

So far I have this:

```
db.getCollection('customers').aggregate([
    {
        $match: {}
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
           from: 'companies',
           localField: 'companyId',
           foreignField: '_id',
           as: 'company'  
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
           companyId: '$company._id',
           companyName: '$company.name',
           shopSetting: '$company.rights.shop'
                
        }
    }
 ])
```

This seems to be working ok to give me all of the companies with their **shop** value (true or false). But what if I only want to see the companies that don't have the shop field existing at all? How would I modify this query to accomplish that? I've tried reading up on the $exists field in mongo, but this is all pretty new to me so I'm not sure where to apply it here.

Note: I need to query the companies from the customers collection because there are some companies without customers and I need this result to only be companies that are assigned to customers but don't have the rights.shop property existing

Answer (score 0):

```
db.customers.aggregate([
  { $match: {} },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "companies",
      localField: "companyId",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "company",
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $eq: [
                {
                  $filter: {
                    input: "$rights",
                    as: "r",
                    cond: "$$r.shop"
                  }
                },
                []
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      companyId: "$company._id",
      companyName: "$company.name",
      shopSetting: "$company.rights.shop"
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/sfj9BLqXFuY)